# Wifi gets hardware-disabled after waking from sleep

Tags: wireless, hardware, atheros

I have an `HP 14-b015dx` device. Whenever I wake my device from sleep the wifi stops working. `Rfkill` shows it is hard bock. Even the wifi light goes orange showing the wifi is disabled by hardware. And i can't switch it on again. (Hardware-switch doesn't work). The only way to get the wifi to work again, is to reboot the device

`lspci | grep -i Wireless` shows:

```
`01:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)`
```

Any help is appreciated!

~Thanks

Comment: You should unset in the wireless connection the checkbox "Connect automatically"

Comment: When you wake the device up again, try to run: `sudo service network-manager stop` then try: `sudo service network-manager start`. 
If this works, let me know.

Comment: Tried Restarting the network-manager but it didnt work and who to i unset Connect automatically

Comment: I have the same issue, and have also tried restarting the network manager.

lspci | grep -i Wireless shows:

01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command from the Terminal when you wake your device from sleep -

```
sudo modprobe -r e1000e ; sudo modprobe e1000e;
```